# How to reset the admin password on Ubuntu 12.04 if the username has a space

Tags: command-line, password, special-characters

I'm having difficulties resetting admin password on my Ubuntu 12.04 if the username has a space eg. Buggs Bunny? At the prompt it will only display Buggs and wont allow the password command to work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write the path of a folder with space in its name?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530578/how-to-write-the-path-of-a-folder-with-space-in-its-name) and [How do I enter a directory with special characters in its name?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101587/how-do-i-enter-a-directory-with-special-characters-in-its-name) Preceding the space character with a backslash \ makes the shell interpret it as a literal space character.

Comment: Spaces are normally used in the shell to separate arguments.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - you are likely confusing the Unix username with the GECOS "fullname" that is used by the GUI login display. See the similar [Cannot login through the command line](https://askubuntu.com/a/498818/178692)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to have a username with a space, you are probably taking about the display name. Have a look of the real username from `cat /etc/passwd`.

Comment: yes thats true, my question would be how did you create a linux user with space in name.

Comment: It's simply not possible, I'm pretty sure that Buggs Bunny is the display name and Buggs is the username. Change the password with `passwd buggs` should be enough.