# New linux user is locked out of his computer after recent upgrade

Tags: boot

Following an update to Linux Ubuntu 22.4, my computer no longer recognizes me as a user. I get the Terminal window, which insists on a user and password. I put in the ones I normally use on the "home" screen (not the terminal screen) but those don't work. There is no data on the computer that isn't backed up, so I could theoretically start from installation again. Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks for helping a new user.

Comment: The name that you "normally use on the "home" screen" is likely your GECOS "fullname" - to log in at the terminal, you need the actual Unix username. See for example [Cannot login through the command line](https://askubuntu.com/a/498818/178692)

Comment: Thank you, but alas, no joy. During the boot up process I pressed down on the shift key when the manufacturer of the computer was displayed. I think I need to further study how to access GRUB.